# How to process the command after pressing Enter in keyDown event for button

Tags: c#, keydown, enter

I'm writing an application controlled only by numblock on keyboard and I need to solve the problem with this code:

```
private void btnSaveCorrection_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("HEY");

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("HEY");
        // Save to DB and jump to next control
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("WTF");
        // if e.KeyCode is [+] or [-], jump to next/previous control
    }
}
```

The problem is:
When I press Enter, nothing happens. When I press any other key, MessageBox "WTF" is showed. Why is all code in KeyDown event ignored when the Enter is pressed? How to fix it?

Thanks for every reply.

Comment: Do you have a default button defined on your page that is grabbing the enter press?

Comment: What is the `KeyCode` when you set a breakpoint after pressing enter? What else happens during that breakpoint debugging?

Comment: It works ok so you must have something else going on. Is it ever getting to the event handler?

Comment: Do you have another control set as the default accept button? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984346%28v=vs.71%29.aspx If you press enter while selecting a button, I believe it will click it and this will be fired before the event handler. Enter and buttons are handled differently - you might want to set EnableKeyPreview to true on the form or something along those lines?

Comment: is this winforms or WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for me it works if you link the KeyUp event instead of the KeyDown Event.

I think the problem is that the enter key is considered a "click" on the button as its default behavior.

My advice is link the KeyUp event instead of the KeyDown event.

Comment: Thank you, the same code in KeyUp event is OK. How is it possible?

Comment: It has to do with the default enter behavior of windows form controls. The Enter key "activates" the control (in the case of a button, it clicks it). Look here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsapps/en-us/f05827a9-181c-48cd-bab2-21aece339032/associating-enter-key-with-a-button